# Slow performance on this std::vector partition

Tags: c++

I've implemented a working `partition` function that behaves like the useful tool of the same name in Clojure. However, mine is very slow. While the Clojure function can partition a million elements completely in a few milliseconds, mine takes several seconds even with 50K elements. (Note: I am not comparing mine to the lazy function call available in Clojure as noted in the comments; I'm talking about the full realization where laziness does not apply).

It and its helpers are:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> take(int size, const std::vector<T>& coll){
    if (size<0) return std::vector<T>();
    auto sized = size > coll.size() ? coll.size() : size;
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator first = coll.begin();
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator last = first + sized;
    return std::vector<T>(first,last);
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> drop(int size, const std::vector<T>& coll){
    if (size<0) return std::vector<T>();
    auto sized = size > coll.size() ? coll.size() : size;
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator first = coll.begin()+sized;
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator last = coll.end();
    return std::vector<T>(first,last);
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> partition(int size, int step, const std::vector<T>& coll, bool showPartialEnd=false){
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> ret;
    ret.reserve(coll.size());
    if (size<1||step<1) return ret;
    std::vector<T> temp;
    std::vector<T> remain=coll;
    auto building=true;
        do {
            temp=std::move(take(size, remain));
            building=(showPartialEnd?(temp.size()>0):(temp.size()==size));
            if (building==true){
                ret.push_back(temp);
                remain=std::move(drop(step, remain));
            }
        } while (building==true);
    return ret;
}
```

I'd love some pointers about where I could optimize this so it behaves much more quickly. I tried reserving size so the `push_back` wouldn't have to allocate everytime, but this made no difference (and actually I've overallocated the size for most use cases). I also thought maybe the `showPartialEnd?` condition might be a roadblock since it doesn't really need to happen with every loop, but splitting into two loops with just one iteration of the condition to select the loop made no difference.

Here is an example use:

```
void examples(){
    auto x=range(30);
    auto y=partition(3, 2, x);
    std::for_each(y.begin(), y.end(), printVector<int>);
}
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 
2 3 4 
4 5 6 
6 7 8 
8 9 10 
10 11 12 
12 13 14 
14 15 16 
16 17 18 
18 19 20 
20 21 22 
22 23 24 
24 25 26 
26 27 28
```

Comment: The documentation for `Clojure`'s partition clearly states that it's lazy: The actual call to partition does almost no work. In C++ you're doing ALL the work up front. This may not in fact be the C++ idiomatic way to solve your real problem.

Comment: @MarkB that's true, but in Clojure I can realize it fully in a few milliseconds. If I do not realize it, then there is no work done and it takes less than 1 millisecond, but I'm referring to the full realization of the sequence.

Comment: Well, I cannot reproduce this on my current system. `partition` seems fast, unless your example is far too minimal. You've tried profiling your program already, right? That being said, your use of `std::move` isn't right.

Comment: @Zeta when you say it seems fast, how fast are you talking, for say 50K elements? The example I posted is only 30 elements but try changing that to 50K and tell me what it gives you.

Comment: You are likely creating lots of copies. Like Zeta said, you should absolutely not use `std::move` on function return values, they are rvalues already. But you should do `ret.push_back(std::move(temp));` to move that into the outer vector. I am also not sure if declaring `temp` outside the loop is a win, as that disables RVO.

Comment: @BoPersson good idea on using move for the push_back. For the temp definition, there is a condition test that depends on it, hence why I declared it.

Comment: @johnbakers: Yes, but you can write `auto temp = take(...)`, and the function would still work. This does not only reduce the scope of `temp` (which is usually a win), but also enables RVO.

Comment: Also, isn't the `drop` call just a complicated way of doing `remain.erase(remain.begin(), remain.begin() + sized)`?

Comment: @Zeta i tried your `auto temp` idea to remove `temp` from the outer scope but it made no difference in the duration of the algorithm

Comment: @BoPersson awesome, thanks! that proved to increase the speed very dramatically!

Comment: Again, you've profiled your program and you know where the bottlenecks are, right? (Am not at my machine anymore, so I cannot do this today). @BoPersson: Yes. But I guess OP wants to go the full "functional style". Which is kind of nonsense. The "fastest" was would return a `std::vector<vector_view>` and not split the actual vector. Takes a lot less memory.

Comment: @Zeta i don't care if the implementation is not functional-like, just that the user of these tools can depend on their speed to write higher-level functional-like idioms. in this case, the drop as mentioned by two commenters proved to be a big bottleneck indeed

Comment: @johnbakers: If you're fully interested in speed, try to come up with a `class vector_view`, which provides an interface into a vector, but doesn't take additional memory (in terms of N, constant memory per `vector_view` is allowed). That's probably the memory-friendliest and one of fastest solutions. (If Clojure lists are anything like Haskell ones, there's a lot of sharing going on behind the scenes, so depending on `step` those languages might take a lot less memory than your current C++ variant).

Comment: @johnbakers: Err, if you replaced the `take` with an `erase`, didn't you accidentially change semantics?

Comment: @Zeta all a take does is erase from an index all the way to the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the performance problem is that your `drop` function turns the algorithm into `O(n^2)` rather than linear time, because it has to keep making a new `remain` container with all the elements that haven't been partitioned out yet.

I'm still trying to grok what the code is intended to do so I could provide a suggestion on how to fix/improve your version.

Totally untested (tight on time right now) but I think this ought to be close:

```
std::vector<std::vector<T>> partition(int size, int step, const std::vector<T>& coll, bool showPartialEnd=false)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> ret;

    if (size<1||step<1) return ret;

    ret.reserve(coll.size() / step + 1);

    std::vector<T>::const_iterator iter = coll.begin();
    for(; ; iter += step)
    {
        // If you have enough elements left for an entire chunk, push it.
        if((coll.end() - iter) >= size)
        {
            ret.push_back(std::vector<T>(iter, iter + size));
        }
        else if(showPartialEnd)
        {
            ret.push_back(std::vector<T>(iter, coll.end()));
            break;   // Remove if you want *all* partial ends instead of just the first one.
        }
        else break;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I have added example output of the function.

Comment: your edit with code sample is a good reminder of the techniques to keep in mind when moving to a language like c++ after working in a higher-level language. yours is much cleaner and simpler by working strictly on iterators without creating new values (copies) along the way